# Unable to setPristine form as want to push my questions in an array

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a quiz application.... but I want questions form users, that's why I decided to make a  form with lots of conditions like (ng-if,ng-show, ng-hide), but I am stuck at last point of [this Application](https://plnkr.co/edit/PZD1QXIirEap3EgXKN1X?p=preview).

and the last point is in the function `addQuestion()` function which is in quiz.controller.js  line @166

and if I am declaring all needed variable empty then it stored empty data in db.json file...

I am unable to figure out where I am mistaken?

**I am unable to setpristine the form while I want to pristine after each and every question insertion.**

and I am using json-server with this although I try to implement data with in quiz.service.js only.
 Please help me.

https://plnkr.co/edit/PZD1QXIirEap3EgXKN1X?p=preview

Comment: Your plunker is not working!!!

Comment: sir actully now i updated my plunker(quiz.service.js && db.json)  files althought it is not working now, but you may download and use that with any local server then it must work an you will get to know that i have to click on first **make your test** button, then it'lll ask for title, decription and no. of question i want to provide then i have to click on **start now** button as when i used to fill questions form then i want to reuse that form untill total no. of question is not completed ??

Comment: Thankyou so much for response sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you didn't mention what error you are facing, my guess is that since you have an `ng-if` right in the beginning of your html block inside the controller block if you call `$scope.queForm` you get undefined.

That is because `ng-if` creates an isolated scope, which means you have two options:

1- Pass the form to addQuestion:

```
$scope.addQuestion = function(queForm){
   //...
   queForm.$setPristine(true); 
};
```

Html:

```
<form name="queForm" ng-submit="addQuestion(queForm)" novalidate>
```

or 2- add your form to an object instead of directly in scope:

```
<form name="myFormContainer.queForm" ng-submit="addQuestion()" novalidate>
```

Then you can access it in your `addQuestion` function:

```
$scope.queForm.$setPristine(true);
```

I created a working sample [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/NhsWk6niZ8wPVUhWh0wB?p=preview).

Comment: hey hello sir thanks again for helping me but i am sorry, both solutions  also not working for me ,
yes you got what exactly i want, actually i want to use form (from line 62 to 268 @index.html) after clicking on submit questions button ,

i tried but i am unable to understand how can i use setpristine() for conditional form ?? , and also i tried mostly all given way on internet, i found i may doing something wrong.......

Comment: Unless you tell me what error are you facing I can't help you anymore. See the update for a working example @A.Sharma

Comment: thanks sir for your reply, but sir i apologize , i'll make it clear to you as i click on submit questions button after filling that question form. i would expect form will be set to its pristine state and untouched state, but instead of that it is showing unable to read property $setPristine() of undefined.... 
i tried both of your solution that you suggest me before, i tried your this updated example also, by the new updated example you give $setPristine() is working but the fields in db submitted as empty...
i think because of i am trying to define all objects as empty.